MYSQL Where IN not working if the parameter is taken/converted from json string
I have a table something like this



id
name




1
A


2
B


3
C



I'm trying to filter it by using WHERE IN from a json string with something like this:
SELECT id, name FROM ref_finding_criterias WHERE id IN (REPLACE(REPLACE('{"criterias":["1","2"]}','{"criterias":[',''),']}',''));

It doesn't work... But when I type it manually like this
SELECT id, name FROM ref_finding_criterias WHERE id IN ("1","2");

It works... any idea how to solve this?
I already tested the formula using
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('{"criterias":["1","2"]}','{"criterias":[',''),']}','');

It does return the same character "1","2" like I manually typed

All you're doing is producing a single string value IN ('"1","2"')

So how do I make it escape the single string value?

You can't do this in a single query in mysql as mysql does not have an array data type. You would have to use a stored procedure that can create a parametrised sql query with the right number of pkaceholders and bind parameters to those placeholders. Simpler to have comma delimited numbers and use find_in_set() instead.

@Shadow so weird that MySQL's JSON_EXTRACT returns a JSON array syntax

@Phil you would still need to use json_contains() instead of in operator with a json array.
